# How to serve static_files in django?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Basically, I am practising an E-commerce project of Django. There are two ways of adding images. ( 1 ) - First is that someone adds the photos manually but I want users to add a photo of the product automatically via static files.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Mobile(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    screen_size = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Samsung')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'This is a mobile'

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price


class MobileImage(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Mobile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.device


class Laptop(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    screen_size = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Dell')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand
```

my views.py:

```
def mobile(request):
    mobiles = Mobile.objects.all()
    context = {
        'mobiles': mobiles
    }
    return render(request, 'device/mobile.html', context)


def laptop(request):
    laptops = Laptop.objects.all()
    context = {
        'laptops': laptops
     }
    return render(request, 'device/laptop.html', context)
```

my mobile.html:

```
 {% extends 'device/base.html' %}

 {% load static %}
 {% block body %}
 <h1>Mobile!</h1>

 <!-- Table -->

 <table class="">
      <tr>
           <h3>Phones:</h3>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Model</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Color</th>
           <th>Screen Size</th>
           <th>OS</th>
           <th>Image</th>
        </tr>

               <body>
               {% for mobile in mobiles %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ forloop.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ mobile.brand }}</td>
                        <td>${{ mobile.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ mobile.color }}</td>
                        <td>{{ mobile.screen_size }}</td>
                        <td>{{ mobile.os }}</td>
                        {% for item in mobile.mobileimage_set.all %}
                            <td><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image }}" alt="No Photo"></td>
                        {% endfor %}
                       </tr>
                {% endfor %}
               </tbody>

    </table>

  {% endblock %}
```

[image]

[image]

In the first image, it showing the path of my static files.
In the second image, it is showing the problem that I am facing.

Comment: you're confusing media with static files. Media is for uploaded content, static is for things that are _static_, like CSS, JS and theme images

Comment: got you. so what is the solution?

Comment: how can I solve this issue?

Comment: My comment was not related to the problem, just a statement - normally you should keep them separate. Back to the problem: looks like you don't have a  url handler for static/media files. Posting your `urls.py` might help

Comment: maybe. how to add url handler?

Comment: did you set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in the `settings.py` and also in the `urls.py` next to the `settings.py` add this lines: `from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static    if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: but there is still a point! the media directory should be at root level, I mean it's best to be in `BASE_DIR`.

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static_files')

Comment: if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: I have already added these settings in my settings,py

Comment: BASE_DIR means out of the app_of_project dir?

Answer (score 0):

replace the `{{ item.image }}` with the following code `{{ item.image.url }}`

Comment: Nothing happened bro

Answer (score 0):

So, what i have done here is basically to remove the image field from the MobileImage class and add to the Mobile class itself. The reason is simply because i noticed you wanted to use a foreign key to relate it but it doesn't look feasible in that context. Incase you have other issues, do let me know.
**P.S: you should run Makemigrations and migrate command as the database has been altered.**

Change your models.py file to this

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    screen_size = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Samsung')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/')

class MobileImage(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Mobile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Change you views.py file to this

```
def mobile(request):
    mobiles = Mobile.objects.all()
    context = {
        'mobiles': mobiles
    }
    return render(request, 'device/mobile.html', context)
```

And your template to this

```
   {% for mobile in mobiles %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ mobile.brand }}</td>
        <td>${{ mobile.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ mobile.color }}</td>
        <td>{{ mobile.screen_size }}</td>
        <td>{{ mobile.os }}</td>
            <td><img src="{{ mobile.image.url }}" alt="No Photo"></td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```